# DimpleJS - Limit the number of category axis values to be displayed in chart

Tags: javascript, charts, dimple.js

For preparing graphs from data that exists in MySQL tables, I am using DimpleJS framework. I am able to plot graphs, everything works. One question though -

In a simple bar chart, with category values on X axis and measure values on Y axis, is there a way to limit the number of X axis categories being displayed? Example, let's say this is my data set: `[(A,1), (B,2), (C,1), (D,5), (E,4)]`
So in my dataset, there are 5 categories (X axis - `A, B,C,D,E`) and corresponding measures that I will be displaying in Y axis. Question is, I just want to display only 3 of the measures - let's say only first three, in this case `(A,1), (B,2) and (C,1)`, although my dataset has two more `(D,5) and (E,4)`.

Is there any way to restrict it in JS/ DimpleJS? I have limited control on the dataset that is coming in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dimple.filterData](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple#filterData) after you receive the dataset but before you provide the data to dimple. This does not mutate the data so won't affect any other operations. I'm not sure what your actual category field is but it should look similar to this :

```
var chartData = dimple.filterData(originalDataset, 'category', ["A", "B", "C"]);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, chartData);
```

Otherwise there is not a provided way to restrict a category axis from showing values present in the data.

Comment: I guess data manipulation is not possible/ good idea using DimpleJS. Thanks for the directions. Good day!.